# Automatically redirect all outbound links on site through disclaimer/tracker page WITHOUT editing them individually

Tags: jquery

I have found a code snippet to pass a outbound link into a disclaimer script on this link:

http://snipplr.com/view/28917/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // BEGIN redirect all outbound links through tracker page
   $("a").click(function(){ 

      // if it's a full URL...
      if ($(this).attr("href").indexOf("http")==0) {

         // if it doesn't go to our site
         if (!/^http(s){0,1}(.){0,3}(www){0,3}(\.){0,1}testando\.br/.test($(this).attr("href"))){

            // send it through the linkout page
            $(this).attr("href","/linkoutpage.php?p=" + $(this).attr("href"))

         }
      } 
   })
   // END redirect all outbound links through tracker page

};
```

But it is redirecting all the links through the script. Can somebody please help me on that? I'm testing with the domain "www.testando.br".

Edit: 
I'm trying to pass all the external links through a script without having the necessity to add "linkoutpage.php?p=THEURL" manually to all the links. Found this script, but somehow all the links are passing through it

Comment: Extremely confused what's even the issue here....

Comment: Sorry for not be clear, I'm trying to pass all the external links through a script without having the necessity to add "linkoutpage.php?p=THEURL" without have to add this manually to all the links. Found this script, but somehow all the links are passing through it.

Comment: Is that `.test` supposed to be in the URL after the `.br/`?

Comment: @Sparky672 it's a RegExp test. Most likely the regexp isn't working properly.

Comment: I've copypasted the regex given by the OP into my sample, it does work; so I guess the problem is somewhere else. Would actually prefer to deploy my answer as a comment, but comments can't be used for such lengthy code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would rewrite this script into something more clear:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var href = this.href;
    var ourDomainRegex = /^https?:\/\/(www[.])?testando[.]br/;
    // those seeking flexibility, consider this: 
    // new RegExp('^https?:\\/\\/(www[.])?'  +  ourDomain)

    if (href.indexOf("http") === 0   &&   ! ourDomainRegex.test(href) )
    {
      this.href = "/linkoutpage.php?p=" + href;
    }
  });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4Zts/) to play with.

Still, I can't find a meaningful difference with the code you've given. Are you sure there's no JavaScript error (you check the console for them)?